# Shortening sass issues

Tags: css, sass

I currently have the following SaSS code

```
$primary: #00a1e5;
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
  @if $i % 5 == 0 {
    $percentage: $i*1%;
    .bg-primary.bg-darken-#{$i} {
      background-color: mix(black, $primary, $percentage)!important;
    }
    .bg-primary.bg-lighten-#{$i} {
      background-color: mix(white, $primary, $percentage)!important;
    }
  }
}
```

I would now like to extend this so that the following is possible:

- I want to be able to insert several such color variables, preferably collected in a group.
- Then I want to be able to use the darken- and lighten- for each of these variables.
- It might be possible to make a collected statement out of the two statements (darken, lighten)
- I could copy the code for each variable and replace the variable name, but that would not be in the spirit of Sass.

Can someone here help me with the coding?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [map](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps) of your colors and [`@each`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each) loop:

```
$colorVariants: (
   primary: #00a1e5,
   secondary: #5f00e5,
   tertiary: #c94dac,
);

@each $colorName, $colorValue in $colorVariants {
   @for $i from 1 through 100 {
      @if $i % 5 == 0 {
         $percentage: $i*1%;
        
         .bg-#{$colorName}.bg-darken-#{$i} {
            background-color: mix(black, $colorValue, $percentage)!important;
         }

         .bg-#{$colorName}.bg-lighten-#{$i} {
            background-color: mix(white, $colorValue, $percentage)!important;
         }
      }
   }
}
```